# Discord.NET sending messages to one specific channel in one specific server

Tags: vb.net, discord.net

So I'm trying to send a message to a specific channel, but I've been looking and found I can't see any way I can do that. I might be doing something wrong or I'm looking in the wrong area, I've looked on Google and couldn't find an answer. This is my code when trying to find it.

```
     discord.GetGuild("serverid").GetChannel("Channelid")
```

As far as I can see, this is not the way to do it, but I don't know where else to check :\

Comment: Have you searched through the documention extensively?

Comment: I have looked through it when trying to find an answer, and from what I looked at I couldn't see anything that would've worked (I tried some).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Actually, I kinda feel stupid after realizing this, In my code previously, I was making the program try and find a channel, when what I actually needed to do was find a text channel, like so:

```
    discord.GetGuild("serverid").GetTextChannel("Channelid").SendMessageAsync(
    "Message")
```

So sorry for asking for help when the answer was really simple.
:/

Comment: Don't apologize for asking on SO. Also, it would be good to mark it as the accepted answer.

Answer (score 1):

when getting the channel you dont need to get the guild, all channels is inside your client
so 
discord.GetTextChannel("id").SendMessageAsync("message") 
would be enough

Comment: Discord.WebSocket.DiscordSocketClient.GetTextChannel does not seem to exist.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old post but for what it is worth this was my solution.  The code is in vb and it works perfectly.

1. Check out .GetAwaiter().GetResult() at the end of the SendMessageAsync() function.  That allows me not to have to put 'await' before that line :).
2. Oh and guild and channel ids are not strings but of Long type
3. I get the IDs from server by searching for the names of each :).  So no need to know the IDs before hand :).

Oh and this function is not of Async type so in your code you need to make adjustments if you are using it as an Async task.

Also the _guild.id and _channel variables are of type ULong.  VB allows u to declare a variable without stating what type it is. VB will automatically detect what type it is based on what is on the right side of the declaration.

```
    Sub sendMessageToChannel(ByVal server As String, ByVal channel As String, ByVal msg As String)
Try
    Dim _guild = _client.Guilds().First(Function(z) z.Name = server)
    Dim _channel = _guild.TextChannels().First(Function(z) z.Name = channel).Id
    _client.GetGuild(_guild.Id).GetTextChannel(_channel).SendMessageAsync(msg).GetAwaiter().GetResult()
Catch ex As Exception
    Debug.Print("Error:" & Constants.vbCrLf + ex.ToString())
End Try     End Sub
```