# Discord.NET C# 1.0.2 How to send messages to specific channels

Tags: c#, discord.net

I am making a bot that can announce messages when specific events happen. Does anyone know how I can output a message to a specific text channel?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Discord.NET sending messages to one specific channel in one specific server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47884627/discord-net-sending-messages-to-one-specific-channel-in-one-specific-server)

Comment: But it is still Discord.Net, and the library usage would be the same for C# as it is for VB.NET.  In fact, appending a semicolon is all that's needed to make the code snippets in that question valid C#.  Speaking of which, one could argue that _this_ question isn't C#, either, because no code was provided.

Comment: And given a VB sample, if you've *tried* to convert that to C# but had problems, that attempt should be in the question.

Comment: "I don't know where to start"-type questions tend to be a [poor fit](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) for Stack Overflow.  There is an expectation that you research and attempt to solve your problem _before_ [asking a question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).  Further, it is appropriate and even encouraged to [answer your own question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer).  That's great that you found a solution to your problem, but if you're not going to share it with the community that would seem to self-fulfill your prophecy of this question being useless.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
public async Task Announce() // 1
{
    DiscordSocketClient _client = new DiscordSocketClient(); // 2
    ulong id = 123456789012345678; // 3
    var chnl = _client.GetChannel(id) as IMessageChannel; // 4
    await chnl.SendMessageAsync("Announcement!"); // 5
}
```

[1] A standard async task (You can choose to just include the code inside the braces inside your own method).
[2] Create an instance of the Discord Client.
[3] A random sequential channel ID (Replace with your own channel ID).
[4] Creating an instance of the Discord Channel as an IMessageChannel instead of a SocketChannel.
[5] Sending the message to the text channel.

Comment: I'm not sure why this was accepted, however, this answer is incorrect. You can't simply create a new `DiscordSocketClient` and use that to do anything. It's not currently logged in and you will not be able to use it to fetch the required channel to send a message. Also, ideally, your app would only have one Client, you wouldn't be creating one each time you need to send a message or get channel, guild or user information.

Answer (score 0):

As @slothgod said

```
    public async Task Announce() // 1
{
    DiscordSocketClient _client = new DiscordSocketClient(); // 2
    ulong id = 123456789012345678; // 3
    var chnl = _client.GetChannel(id) as IMessageChannel; // 4
    await chnl.SendMessageAsync("Announcement!"); // 5
}
```

The above code works when you want to send reply pre-fixed messages(Like "Announcement!" in above code) in only one channel. You can change the channel in "ulong id = ....your channel id here....;"

But if you want to send custom messages to custom channel then try this code.

```
    public async Task _say(IMessageChannel chh,[Remainder]string repeat)
{
    await Context.Message.DeleteAsync();
    await chh.SendMessageAsync(repeat); // 5
}
```

To use the code I sent just type this command : `"Your Bot Prefix and Command" "Channel name or ID" "Message you want to send"`

Example : `DFH.say TestChannel Welcome to this channel`

Answer (score 0):

What I did was:
used dependency injection to have the logged-in client available wherever I wanted to send the message, in my case, it was a Module.

```
public XModule(DiscordSocketClient client){
 this.client = client;
}
```

Then as @slothgod said:

```
 private async Task Announce(ExampleType object) //1
        {
            ulong id = object.ChannelId; // 3
            var chnl = client.GetChannel(id) as IMessageChannel; // 4
            await chnl.SendMessageAsync("Message!"); // 5
        }
```

Answer (score -1):

```
public async Task TalkInChannel() //1
{
   DiscordSocketClient _client = new DiscordSocketClient(); //2
   var channel = _client.GetChannel(Channel ID) as SocketGuildChannel; //3
   await channel.SendMessageAsync("Message Here!"); //4
}
```

> You can also use embeds by creating an Embed then replacing "Message Here!" with """, false EmbedName.Build()"